# When we talk about a ray of light (radiation), is the ray a single pulse of electromagnetic disturbance or a train on pulses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

When we talk about a ray of light or any other radiation, is the ray a single pulse of electromagnetic disturbance or a train on pulses? And if it's a train then can we say where the position of the photon(s) is?

Answer (score 3):

A ray is a continuous beam from a source to a point of interception. It is a path followed by billions of photons, each of which is associated with a wave packet of finite size and measurable energy.